# fastlane boarding process for fabric beta webpage setup

Tags: ios, beta, fastlane, fabric-beta

There is fastlane boarding for testflight to distribute builds using webpage

https://github.com/fastlane/boarding

Does it exists for fabric beta testing? what is the config for that , if yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric & Firebase here. I think you're looking for "Share Links" from Beta. After your first build, you can click on Share Links under the Beta tab.

[image: Share Links]

From there, you click on "+ Create New"

[image: Click on Create New]

and then setup the link with the necessary information. You can also optionally an email domain restriction if you only want testers from your company's domain.

[image: Set up share link]

After that, you'll have a static page where folks can sign up to test.

[image: Enter email address for beta app access]